# ArcGIS 10.2.2 Does "Batch Project" work for different input datum?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, datum, nad83

I have two vector data sets - one is in NAD27 and the other is in WGS84. Normally I reproject one at a time. But can I just use 'batch project' to reproject both of them to NAD83 at once? I was not sure if the input datum must be the same for all files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe I've ever tried it but you can set the Geographic transformations in the 'Environment Settings' of the Batch Project Tool (see attached screen shot). 
Note: You will have to figure out which exact transformation you require (depends on the geographic area you're dealing with. The '_6' for example is for a specific region. See this page for more details: [About Geographic Transformations](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/05/06/about-geographic-transformations-and-how-to-choose-the-right-one/) 
Hopefully this helps. Let us know if it works out for you. 
 [image]

Comment: Just tried it (had to convert datasets to WGS1984 and NAD1927 first). But it does work, I successfully managed to convert both datasets with different datums to NAD83 setting the right transformations. It may even automatically select the correct transformations for you once you enter the output coordinate system.